# Texture (from texture paint mode) not showing up in object or edit modes

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm fairly new to Blender, so forgive me if I'm asking a simple question. I've followed tutorial after tutorial and no one seems to have this problem.

I unwrapped my model, painted it (poorly), and everything is hunky-dory as far as viewing it in texture paint mode. However, when I switch to object mode, the model doesn't show the texture. What am I doing wrong? I know that if I need it to render properly I need to set a material and everything, but shouldn't it show in the object view?

Texture Paint Mode:
[image: texture paint mode]

Object Mode (note: "Textured Solid" under Shading is enabled)
[image: object mode]

Even if I set the dropdown menu at the bottom to "Texture" it doesn't display a texture.

What dumb mistake am I making here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a material to display the texture, if you were creating a texture in paint mode it would add the texture node automatically in your material.

Comment: I did use paint mode, but I must have done something wrong because it didn't do anything like that automatically. Is there a good tutorial for how to set that up manually, I wonder?

Comment: Nevermind, just figured it out. I feel silly. In all the tutorials I watch it does seem to be creating it automatically. I wonder what I did differently. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What happened is you were in solid shading mode, not texture mode

Comment: Naw, what happened is that the texture and material weren't generated automatically when I did texture painting, so I had to go in and create them myself from the image.

Comment: hi i am facing the same problem. can you please explain in detail how did you fix it? thanks in advance.